# How to retrieve large text in Json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sql-server-2005, asp-classic

I have a text field in a table SQL server. I need to retrieve this field like an attribute. I'm using ASP to generate this JSON file.

something like...

```
[{"name":"name of object","observation":"   

 Text text text text text
 text text text text

 text text text text

 text text text text

 text"}]
```

I already tried some replace functions both in ASP as javascript but it didn't work . 
Any idea?

The JSON file is obtained in the following way:

```
//call json 
    var json = (function () {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            global: false,
            url: 'functions.asp?' + params,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                json = data;
            }

        });
        return json;
    })(); 

    var tam = json.length;
```

In the last line I'm gettin' a "json is null".

UPDATE :

The problem was the enter key that was retrieved in the text.

Comment: Are you generating this json yourself, or are you using a built-in asp method or library to do it.

Comment: I'm generating by myself, but using Response.AddHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')" and without this large atribute works well.

Comment: i don't think line breaks are allowed in a Json string... you have to replace the line breaks with something (obviously \\\)

Comment: I tried to replace but didn't work, I think is because it is a plain text.

Comment: @luckasx so how does your json look like now? after you have replaced the line breaks? you can always test your json here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: look in the same format and doesnt work

Comment: Marcel asked already, what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is the result isn't reconigzed like a JSON file . For example if I try a json.length I got a "json is null"